# Rocky Linux 8 & 9: C++/Qt application crashes with "Failed to load /usr/share/icons/Adwaita/16x16/status/image-missing.png"

Tags: c++, qt5, gtk, libpng, rocky-os

On Rocky Linux 8 and 9, I encounter a problem, my Qt/C++ application crashes due to some actions that require to open a QFileDialog with the message:

```
(myapp:2992): Gtk-WARNING **: 14:52:45.518: Could not load a pixbuf from icon theme.
This may indicate that pixbuf loaders or the mime database could not be found.
**
Gtk:ERROR:gtkiconhelper.c:494:ensure_surface_for_gicon: assertion failed (error == NULL): Failed to load /usr/share/icons/Adwaita/16x16/status/image-missing.png: Fatal error reading PNG image file: bad parameters to zlib (gdk-pixbuf-error-quark, 0)
Abandon (core dumped)
```

The file **/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/16x16/status/image-missing.png** exists provided by the official package adwaita-icon-theme

```bash
$ ls -li /usr/share/icons/Adwaita/16x16/status/image-missing.png
309636 -rwxrwxrwx. 1 etude etude 405 Apr 21  2022 /usr/share/icons/Adwaita/16x16/status/image-missing.png
```

Furthermore, my application does not crash when iit is launched with **sudo**, or when it is launched using a remote X11 server.

More information:

- Linux version: Rocky Linux 8.8 or 9.1
- Qt5 version: 5.15.3

I've already tried to:

- Change the permissions on then repository **/usr/share/mime:**

  ```bash
  $ sudo  chmod -R 777 /usr/share/mime
  ```
- Update the mime database:

  ```bash
  $ sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime
  ```
- Update the cache using:

  ```bash
  $ sudo gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders-64 --update-cache
  ```